# ModuleId required for crowdfunding recipe is not present

Tags: substrate, polkadot

The [crowdfunding app](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/recipes/blob/master/pallets/simple-crowdfund/src/lib.rs) has an import ModuleId

```
use sp_runtime::{
    traits::{AccountIdConversion, Saturating, Zero},
    ModuleId,
};

const PALLET_ID: ModuleId = ModuleId(*b"ex/cfund");
```

I am now using FRAME 2.0, sp_runtime no more contain [ModuleId](https://crates.parity.io/sc_service/index.html?search=ModuleId), what is the alternative for it?

```
unresolved import `sp_runtime::ModuleId`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ModuleId` -> `PalletId`
Occurred here: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/8477